# Copying layer in to multiple compositions - After Effects

Tags: javascript, extendscript, after-effects

I'm trying to copy a background image layer in to multiple compositions without having to copy and paste to every composition.

I found the following code below...however I have very basic knowledge of javascript and I'm unsure how to apply this to the project.

```
for (i = 1; i<=app.project.numItems; i++){
    if ((app.project.item(i).typeName=="Composition") && (i!=1)) app.project.item(1).layer(1).copyToComp(app.project.item(i));
}
```

I've tried running this on After Effects and I get the result:

> Function app.project.item().layer is undefined

Are there specific things in the code I need to modify to make this work?

I've tried changing the value of Composition to the name of the composition where the layer is and then I get the result:

> Execution finished. Result: undefined

Comment: The items in `app.project` may not be sorted the way you think they're sorted. Most likely `app.project.item(1)` is not the comp you think it is, which is why you're getting the first error message. The second message is just the message you get when a script runs without an error.

Comment: Thanks very much. It turned out to be item(2)

Comment: I'm now trying to do something similar.  how ever it keeps saying "Expected;" Any ideas?

I want to copy an effects layer to all the footage layers on all the compositions. The effect is "keylight 1.2" and the parameter is "Screen Gain"


    ```for (i = 1; i<=app.project.numItems; i++){
if ((app.project.item(i).typeName=="Composition"))
{
app.project.item(5).layer(1).effect(3)property(5).copyToComp(app.project.item(i).layer(1));}
} ```

Comment: You should ask that in a new question. I'm thinking that you're trying to copy a property of an effect to a layer object. You might need to apply the effect, then copy the parameter.

Comment: thanks will do. So do you mean i need to write a separate line which applies the effect  before ``` app.project.item(5).layer(1).effect(3).property(5).copyToComp(app.project.item(i).layer(1));} } ```

Comment: yup. Can't guarantee it will work tho.

Answer (score 0):

The code works like a charm with no problems. Basically, you just have to put your comp as the first item. The VERY first item in your project list. Then, the script will copy the first layer from your composition and paste it into every single composition.